# How to implement WebViewJavascriptBridge in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I work on iOS projects that use UIWebViews to present content. I often need that content to communicate with the native app, and for that I rely on the helpful [WebViewJavascriptBridge](https://github.com/marcuswestin/WebViewJavascriptBridge).

I started a new project that I wanted to implement in Swift. Being new to the language, I had issues with correctly implementing the bridge. Although I'll readily admit inexperience for part of the issue, I also realized that Xcode was completing the code somewhat incorrectly, especially when setting up the closures where the Objective-C library uses blocks.

This is the code I used in Objective-C, where some Javascript is sending over a dictionary to present a PDF:

```
@weakify(self);
self.bridge = [WebViewJavascriptBridge bridgeForWebView:self.webView webViewDelegate:self handler:^(id data, WVJBResponseCallback responseCallback) {
    @strongify(self);
    if ([data isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {

        // show a pdf
        if ([data[@"type"] isEqualToString:@"pdf"]) {
            self.docString = data[@"file"];
            self.docTitle = data[@"title"];
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"modalPDF" sender:self];
        }
}
}];
```

In addition to setting up the bridge correctly, I needed to make sure to use a [weak reference](http://aceontech.com/objc/ios/2014/01/10/weakify-a-more-elegant-solution-to-weakself.html) to `self` in Swift as I do above in the Objective-C code.

How would one correctly implement the bridge in Swift?

Answer (score 5):

It took me some trial and error, but I did find a solution that works well.

The first thing I did after adding the WebViewJavascriptBridge to my project was to create an [Objective-C Bridging Header](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/buildingcocoaapps/MixandMatch.html) in my project and import the class there:

```
#import "WebViewJavascriptBridge.h"
```

With that in place, I was able to initialize the bridge with the following code:

```
self.bridge = WebViewJavascriptBridge(forWebView: self.webView, webViewDelegate: self) {
    [unowned self](data, responseCallback) -> Void in

    if let dataObj = data as? Dictionary<String, String> {
        if (dataObj["type"] == "pdf") {
            self.docString = dataObj["file"]
            self.docTitle = dataObj["title"]
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("modalPDF", sender: self)
        }
    }
}
```

Please note that in lieu of a weak reference to `self` I used `[unowned self]` as [documented by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html).

Answer (score 0):

`WebViewJavascriptBridge` long time have no maintain.

Maybe you should change to use this library.

[SDBridgeSwift](https://github.com/SDBridge/SDBridgeSwift)

This can easy to get javascript console.log.Another use should not change.
And `window.WebViewJavascriptBridge` will never mount fail .

```
bridge.consolePipeClosure = { water in
         guard let jsConsoleLog = water else {
             print("Javascript console.log give native is nil!")
              return
         }
         print("Next line is Javascript console.log----->>>>>>>")
         print(jsConsoleLog)
      }
```

Also have h5 demo for your partner.